# Share network between android emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using NSD to create services. Currently I'm using 2 emulators, one for creating NSD service and one for discovery of NSD service but since network between emulators is not shared so I'm not able to discover my service in my second emulator.

So my question is how can I share network between Android emulators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we can't share network between android emulators. In future android might provide support for WIFI driver then we can use single wifi router to share network.